# Is passing an object through constructors, to multiple fragments a bad practice?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-mvvm

In my app I have one activity which has a RecyclerView adapter using a List of `OrderItems`

When a user clicks on an item, I pass the object from my `RecyclerAdapter` to my MainActivity to inflate a `BottomSheetDialog`

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        . . .

        int position;

        ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            . . .

            adapterCallback.onOrderItemClick(orderItem);
        }
    }

public interface OrdersAdapterCallback {
        void onOrderItemClick(OrderItem orderItem);
}
```

In the implemented interface callback method inside my `MainActivity`, I inflate the `BottomSheetDialog` using the object from my adapter (First time the object is passed)

`MainActivity`

```
@Override
    public void onOrderItemClick(OrderItem orderItem) {
        //Object passed from adapter
        BottomSheetDialogFragment dialogFragment = BottomSheetOrderFragment.newInstance(orderItem);
        dialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), Constants.FRAGMENT_BOTTOMSHEET_ORDER);
    }
```

When the `BottomSheetDialog` is inflated, there is a button that dismisses this current dialog, and inflates a `FragmentDialog` that passes that `OrderItem` (but after using some setters on it) object again (second time the object is passed).

`Inside the BottomSheetDialog:`

```
private BottomSheetOrderFragment(OrderItem orderItem){
        this.orderItem = orderItem;
        this.orderItem.setNewOrder("New order string here");
}

@OnClick(R.id.btn_edit_order)
    void onEditOrderBtnClick(){
    dismiss();
    mainActivity.editOrder(this.orderItem);
}
```

So currently we have passed the `OrderItem` object to two different fragments inside the `MainActivity`. I then have to pass this object to the `MainViewModel`, and then to the `MainRepo` where the `RoomDatabase` class inserts that object into the local db.

This ends up having the `OrderItem` to be passed through 4 different classes through their constructors, and on the way a few setters are applied to that object. My question is, is this a bad practice in Android / OOP in general? Or is there a better way of doing what I'm trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is, is this a bad practice in Android / OOP in general?

Yes.

> Or is there a better way of doing what I'm trying to achieve?

Probably.

*What* that is is hard to say since it's not fully clear what you're trying to achieve and how this code is structured.

But I would advise you check out [this documentation on sharing data between fragments](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing). With that in mind, consider keeping this `OrderItem` object in *one* place - the `ViewModel` - then accessing the one shared view model from each `Fragment` or `Activity` that needs to work with / on the order item.

Answer (score 1):

Its not a bad practice but however a good one will be to use a shared viewmodel from which the fragments can access the data they need